# Всегда ли я могу управлять выводом команды в Bash?

Tags: less, bash, linux

Вожусь с Hadoop. Запустил hdfs namenode -format. Он выдавал какие-то ошибки которые я не видел тк строки бежали слишком быстро. Я попытался написать

```
hdfs namenode -format | ls

hdfs namenode -format > result.txt
```

.. однако и то, и другое результата не дало.

Я правильно делал?
Почему не смог управлять выводом?

Comment: @KutaBeach, если я ничего не путаю, таким образом вы управляете только stdout, а ошибки могут лететь в stderr. Тут я уже совсем плаваю, но вроде бы 2>&1 перенаправит stderr в stdout:

    hdfs namenode -format > result.txt 2>&1

Что до `| ls`, то ls выводит содержимое директории, вы вряд ли хотели эту команду использовать.

Comment: @Etki лучше так

   hdfs namenode -format &> result.txt

, а интерактивно, действительно

   hdfs namenode -format 2>&1 |less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы перехватить как стандартный поток, так и поток ошибок в bash:

```
$ hdfs namenode -format |& less
```

Иногда приложения пишут напрямую в терминал ([пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9405235/4279)), в таких случаях можно использовать `screen`, чтобы перехватить вывод:

```
$ screen -L -- hdfs namenode -format
$ mv screenlog.0 result.txt
```